# POST: register return The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST in laravel-api 8

Tags: laravel, routes, methods

After I deployed my project to server the Route: register start return this:

> ```
> "message": "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.",
> "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
> ```

in localhost, it worked succesful!

My route list is:

> | POST| api/register | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\UserAuthController@register

My route in api.php:

```
Route::post('register', [UserAuthController::class, 'register']);
```

Controller:

```
class UserAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
            'phone_number' => 'required|numeric|unique:users,phone_number',
            'country' => 'required|string',
            'city' => 'required|string',
            'address' => 'string',
            'VIP' => 'boolean'
        ]);

        $data['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);

        $user = User::create($data);

        $token = $user->createToken('API Token')->accessToken;

        return response(['user' => $user, 'token' => $token], 201);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried php artisan route:clear and php artisan cache:clear on server?

Comment: How do you actually call this route from the client?

Comment: @parastoo yes i try this, same problem

Comment: @MátyásGrőger like that: {{URL}}/register

Comment: It seems these codes do not have any problems, You deployed that API , so test the backend with postman on server , if it works you should check your form

Comment: @parastoo I Got this in postman in server:
 "message": "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.", "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
 "file": "/home/X/www.X.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php",
"line": 117,
"trace": [
{
"file": "/home/X/www.X.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php",
"line": 103,
"function": "methodNotAllowed",
"class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\AbstractRouteCollection",
"type": "->"
},

Comment: please run this : php artisan optimize:clear and again php artisan route:clear . the first one clears all cached data

Comment: @parastoo, Nothing changed after running these commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was from the host not the project, When you face this problem and the project worked in your local host but facing this problem in the server just check if you enable **HTTPS** protocol in cPanel or in **.htacsses** in the root path.

After you do this your project should work successfully.

Answer (score 0):

use the following commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

**update:**

if it doesn't work check if the url the same `{url}/api/register`

Comment: I tried but Not work!

Comment: check the update

Comment: Yes its the same.
I Deploy the project on subdomain, I dont now if this matter

Comment: It worked on my localhost

Comment: it works on localhost on postman?

Comment: YES, it works 100%

Answer (score 0):

I was testing my API (Laravel 8) via Postman and discovered that accidentally adding a `/` to the end of the request was causing this error.